# Prevent self closing tags in XmlSerializer when no data is present

Tags: c#, .net, xml

When I serialize the value : If there is no value present in for data then it's coming like below format.

```
  <Note>
        <Type>Acknowledged by PPS</Type>
        <Data />
  </Note>
```

**But what I want xml data in below format:**

```
  <Note>
        <Type>Acknowledged by PPS</Type>
        <Data></Data>
  </Note>
```

Code For this i have written :

```
[Serializable]
public class Notes
{
    [XmlElement("Type")]
    public string typeName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Data")]
    public string dataValue { get; set; }
}
```

I am not able to figure out what to do for achieve data in below format if data has n't assign any value.

```
  <Note>
        <Type>Acknowledged by PPS</Type>
        <Data></Data>
  </Note>
```

Comment: While I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, note that the xml you wrote is actually invalid. You never close the Data element.

Comment: If I use this then [XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable = false)] <Data></Data> completely ignore that i don't want

Comment: The times when the difference between <Data/> and <Data></Data> actually matters is small, and usually directly tied to incomplete/buggy implementations. Why do you want this?

Comment: Because I am doing some operation if there is no element found in <Data></Data> value

Comment: You should read my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786561/null-elements-not-showing-in-response-xml-soap-web-service/10788234#10788234) and apply it to Your situation.

Comment: check out this link http://forums.asp.net/t/1837885.aspx/1?XmlTextWriter+full+end+elements+hide+empty+elements+in+XmlSerializer+Serialize+ it may help to accomplish what you need

Answer (score 15):

You can do this by creating your own XmlTextWriter to pass into the serialization process.

```
public class MyXmlTextWriter : XmlTextWriter
{
    public MyXmlTextWriter(Stream stream) : base(stream, Encoding.UTF8)
    {

    }

    public override void WriteEndElement()
    {
        base.WriteFullEndElement();
    }
}
```

You can test the result using:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Notes));
            var writer = new MyXmlTextWriter(stream);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, new Notes() { typeName = "Acknowledged by PPS", dataValue="" });
            var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
       Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Caution: this will result in `null -> ""` when serialized/deserialized.

Comment: Works, but then the XML is generated without line breaking after each element :(

Comment: @SuperJMN You need to wrap around an `XmlWriter`. The underlying `XmlWriter` needs `XmlWriterSettings` with `Indent` set to `true` and `NewLineChars` set to something sensible. Example: http://pastebin.com/G2bZNQnQ (also works with `Stream` instead of `TextWriter`)

Comment: It has a bag on Indented mode. This https://stackoverflow.com/a/40423636/4594225 is working for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you saved your string somewhere (e.g a file) you can use this simple Regex.Replace:

```
var replaced = Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(name), @"<([^<>/]+)\/>", (m) => $"<{m.Groups[1].Value.Trim()}></{m.Groups[1].Value.Trim()}>");
File.WriteAllText(name, replaced);
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO it's not possibe to generate your desired XML using `Serialization`. But, you can use `LINQ to XML` to generate the desired schema like this -

```
XDocument xDocument = new XDocument();
XElement rootNode = new XElement(typeof(Notes).Name);
foreach (var property in typeof(Notes).GetProperties())
{
   if (property.GetValue(a, null) == null)
   {
       property.SetValue(a, string.Empty, null);
   }
   XElement childNode = new XElement(property.Name, property.GetValue(a, null));
   rootNode.Add(childNode);
}
xDocument.Add(rootNode);
XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent=true };
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("D:\\Sample.xml", xws))
{
    xDocument.Save(writer);
}
```

Main catch is `in case your value is null, you should set it to empty string`. It will `force the closing tag to be generated`. In case value is null closing tag is not created.

Answer (score 1):

Kludge time - see [Generate System.Xml.XmlDocument.OuterXml() output thats valid in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817060/generate-system-xml-xmldocument-outerxml-output-thats-valid-in-html)

Basically after XML doc has been generated go through each node, adding an empty text node if no children

```
// Call with
addSpaceToEmptyNodes(xmlDoc.FirstChild);

private void addSpaceToEmptyNodes(XmlNode node)
{
    if (node.HasChildNodes)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
            addSpaceToEmptyNodes(child);
    }
    else         
        node.AppendChild(node.OwnerDocument.CreateTextNode(""))
}
```

*(Yes I know you shouldn't have to do this - but if your sending the XML to some other system that you can't easily fix then have to be pragmatic about things)*

Comment: I had to change `if (node.HasChildNodes)` to `if (node.HasChildNodes && node.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Text)`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a dummy field to prevent the self-closing element.

```
[XmlText]
public string datavalue= " ";
```

Or if you want the code for your class then Your class should be like this.

```
public class Notes
{
   [XmlElement("Type")]
   public string typeName { get; set; }

   [XmlElement("Data")]
   private string _dataValue;
   public string dataValue {
      get {
          if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_dataValue))
             return " ";
          else
             return _dataValue;
      }
      set {
          _dataValue = value;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: " " is still value.

Answer (score 0):

In principal, [armen.shimoon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13540468/8640292) worked for me. But if you want your XML output pretty printed without having to use XmlWriterSettings and an additional Stream object (as stated in the comments), you can simply set the Formatting in the constructor of your XmlTextWriter class.

```
public MyXmlTextWriter(string filename) : base(filename, Encoding.UTF8)
{
    this.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
}
```

(Would have posted this as a comment but am not allowed yet ;-))

Answer (score 0):

Effectively the same as Ryan's solution which uses the standard XmlWriter (i.e. there's no need for a derived XmlTextWriter class), but written using linq to xml (XDocument)..

```
private static void AssignEmptyElements(this XNode node)
{     
    if (node is XElement e)
    {
        e.Nodes().ToList().ForEach(AssignEmptyElements);

        if (e.IsEmpty)
            e.Value = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

usage..

```
AssignEmptyElements(document.FirstNode);
```