# XML serialization force full closing tag on null or empty value

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have class

```
public class Testowa
{
    public string test { get; set; }
}
```

When I serialize it without value for test, I get

```
<test/>
```

But I want get

```
<test></test>
```

How I can do it?

Comment: they mean the same thing.  Why does it matter?

Comment: `<test/>` and `<test></test>` are equivalent in XML. Why is the difference significant to you?

Comment: I have to adapt to the clinet specification. I don't know why he want so.

Comment: aside from that, you haven't told us what you've tried or even how you are going about serializing the class.  There's not enough information here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539555/prevent-self-closing-tags-in-xmlserializer-when-no-data-is-present

Comment: When a person asks 'How?', don't invalidate it with a 'Why?'. Here's a case I'd run across for requesting full closing tags: A legacy application is being revamped. It has to be improved incrementally and the area of focus at the moment is on the serialization of an object. New public properties are being defined and the developer wants to be able to hand edit the XML as a sort of template that can be loaded back in. Having the full closing tag is less typing of text elements when you have a few dozen nodes you want to toy with.

Comment: Well said @KevinScharnhorst. In my case I have to submit XML to a state regulatory agency. I can't argue, I just need to know if this is possible and if it is, how to do it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Extend XmlWriter

From [there](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27641357/XmlWriter-Create-Empty-Tag-tag-tag.html),

If you use a code similar to the following for your serialization:

```
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Testowa));
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(File, FileMode.CreateNew))
{
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
    settings.NewLineChars = Environment.NewLine;
    settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document;
    settings.Indent = true;
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fs, settings))
    {
        s.Serialize(writer, this);
    }
}
```

Replace the last line with a derived version of `XmlWriter` which will force the serialization of full closing tags:

```
s.Serialize(new XmlWriterEE(writer), this);
```

**The full XmlWriter derived class:**

```
public class XmlWriterEE :  XmlWriter
{
    private XmlWriter baseWriter;

    public XmlWriterEE(XmlWriter w)
    {
        baseWriter = w;
    }

    //Force WriteEndElement to use WriteFullEndElement
    public override void WriteEndElement() {baseWriter.WriteFullEndElement(); }

    public override void WriteFullEndElement()
    {
        baseWriter.WriteFullEndElement();
    }

    public override void Close()
    {
        baseWriter.Close();
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        baseWriter.Flush();
    }

    public override string LookupPrefix(string ns)
    {
        return (baseWriter.LookupPrefix(ns));
    }

    public override void WriteBase64(byte[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        baseWriter.WriteBase64(buffer, index, count);
    }

    public override void WriteCData(string text)
    {
        baseWriter.WriteCData(text);
    }

    public override void WriteCharEntity(char ch)
    {
        baseWriter.WriteCharEntity(ch);
    }

    public override void WriteChars(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        baseWriter.WriteChars(buffer, index, count);
    }

    public override void WriteComment(string text)
    {
        baseWriter.WriteComment(text);
    }

    public override void WriteDocType(string name, string pubid, string sysid, string subset)
    {
        baseWriter.WriteDocType(name, pubid, sysid, subset);
    }

    public override void WriteEndAttribute()
    {
        baseWriter.WriteEndAttribute();
    }

    public override void WriteEndDocument()
    {
        baseWriter.WriteEndDocument();
    }

    public override void WriteEntityRef(string name)
    {
        baseWriter.WriteEntityRef(name);
    }

    public override void WriteProcessingInstruction(string name, string text)
    {
        baseWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction(name, text);
    }

    public override void WriteRaw(string data)
    {
        baseWriter.WriteRaw(data);
    }

    public override void WriteRaw(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        baseWriter.WriteRaw(buffer, index, count);
    }

    public override void WriteStartAttribute(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
    {
        baseWriter.WriteStartAttribute(prefix, localName, ns);
    }

    public override void WriteStartDocument(bool standalone)
    {
        baseWriter.WriteStartDocument(standalone);
    }

    public override void WriteStartDocument()
    {
        baseWriter.WriteStartDocument();
    }

    public override void WriteStartElement(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
    {
        baseWriter.WriteStartElement(prefix, localName, ns);
    }

    public override WriteState WriteState
    {
        get { return baseWriter.WriteState; }
    }

    public override void WriteString(string text)
    {
        baseWriter.WriteString(text);
    }

    public override void WriteSurrogateCharEntity(char lowChar, char highChar)
    {
        baseWriter.WriteSurrogateCharEntity(lowChar, highChar);
    }

    public override void WriteWhitespace(string ws)
    {
        baseWriter.WriteWhitespace(ws);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this, didn't work, pulled my hair out, spent hours and hours trying to figure out why it's not working or what I'm supposed to do and why NOBODY has a current solution... then I realized that I was opening the produced XML file in the Windows default application for XML - Internet Explorer. IE was loading the XML file and re-displaying it in "modern" XML standard. When I opened the actual file in Notepad++, I saw that the open and close tags were, in fact, in the file. I'm assuming IE loaded the document and displayed it with their own XML viewer that converts `<tag></tag>` to `<tag/>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wont use FileStream, you may use StringBuilder. XmlWriterEE class from [Fab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5328150/fab) post.

```
    public static string SerializeObject(this object obj)
    {
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"),
            NewLineChars = Environment.NewLine,
            ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto,
            OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
            WriteEndDocumentOnClose = true,
            Indent = true
        };           

        var stream = new StringBuilder();

        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
        {
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(new XmlWriterEE(writer), obj, namespaces);                
        }
        return stream.ToString();
    }
```